# GRUB on trying to install Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: grub2, system-installation, 20.10

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.10 from an USB that I've created on Debian from an image downloaded just today. On starting from USB, the only thing I can see is "GRUB" on screen and that's all.

I've installed previous versions without problems on the same computer. It's an HP Pavilion dv6.

What can I do?

Thank you.

Comment: I've tryed with diferents flavours of Ubuntu: "Principal" and Mate. And the problem is the same. Any sugestion?

Comment: The problem goes on with all the versions I've tried. ¿Any sugestion?